# Deduce the conclusion from the premise.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Use the valid argument form to deduce the conclusion
from the premises, giving a reason for each step.

A. ~p v q ➵ r

B. s v ~q

C.~t

D.  p ➵ t

E. ~p Λ r ➵  ~s

F. (conclusion) ~q

So Far this is my work.

1. p➵   t  ( p implies t, if p then t, modus tolltens)

~t

conclusion ~p

2. ~p ➵  q

(conclusion) ~p v q (generalization)

3. ~p v q ➵  r

~ p v q

r

This is where I get stuck. Does anyone know what to do next and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\neg p\lor q\to r$ - Premise

$s\lor \neg q$ - Premise

$\neg t$ - Premise

$p\to t$ - Premise

$\neg p\land r\to \neg s$ - Premise

$\neg p$ - Modus Tollens

$\neg p\lor q$ - "or" introduction

$r$ - Modus Ponens

$\neg p\land r$ - "and" introduction

$\neg s$ - Modus Ponens

$\neg q$ - Disjunctive Syllogism